# Modeling a binary outcome based on multiple predictor variables (when measures within subjects exclude one another)

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, predictive-models, repeated-measures

The study design is as follows:

> N subjects received MRI examinations. In a subset of cases, one or more sequences (i.e. separate “components” of the examination) were of insufficient image quality (e.g. due to motion artifacts) and therefore reacquired. For all sequences with >1 acquisitions, exactly one was selected for further use solely based on visual impression (even if all acquisitions were quite “bad”, one of them still had to be selected). For all acquisitions there is also a set of quantitative (continuous) quality parameters.

I want to predict the binary outcome of an acquisition being selected or not selected for use (dependent variable) based on the quantitative quality parameters (multiple independent predictor variables, within-subject comparison). I find it complex because acquisitions were not assessed and categorized individually, but always in comparison to at least one more acquisition of the same sequence within a subject. These acquisitions „mutually exclude“ one another, since only one of them could be selected for further use.

My ideas so far, but I'm not sure:

- mixed effects logistic regression
- some kind of repeated measures approach
- discrete choice model

**Edit:** Sample size: 80-400 subjects depending on the sequence, which should be analysed separately.
Predictors: 3-10 depending on the sequence. The predictors are continuous measures of image properties, such as sharpness, noise signal-to-noise ratio etc.

Comment: What is your sample size? How many predictors? What do they measure? ...

Comment: I added the requested information to the original post.